# Compile error when I link Bullet physics

Tags: c++, linker, bulletphysics

I've downloaded the bullet physics library, used CMake with default settings to make a Code::Blocks project for it and built it. I have then added the lib folder to the library path and added the src folder to the include path. When I compile my project with `-lBulletCollision -lBulletDynamics -lLinearMath` I get (among others) this error message:

```
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libBulletDynamics.a(btRigidBody.obj):btRigidBody.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
```

I've read on the Internet that that compile error frequently occurs when you have compiled stuff with different exception mechanisms (DW2 and SJLJ), but I've compiled both Bullet and my project with the same compiler config.

Comment: What are the build and linkage commands you used?

Comment: I kept both at default aside from enabling C++11 for my project (`-std=c++11`). I think Code::Blocks just runs g++ without any additional flags if you don't change anything.

Comment: @user2779931 Why don't you find out instead of guessing? All the command details executed by codeblocks is under build logs.

Comment: Just looked there and I was right.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this even if it's old just in case sombody else stumbles upon it.

It's been a while but I remember getting stuck by not linking in the correct order. I just looked in an old successful project and the order is BulletDynamics at the top then BulletCollission and last LinearMath. I'm pretty sure I used Code::Blocks v 10 and GCC 4.3 back then.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this, it saved me from a lot of unnecessary headache!